# Change font size at run time android

Tags: android, android-xml, android-fonts

I have one `textview` and it has size as `32sp` in `xml`.

```
android:textSize="32sp"
```

I wanted to change it as `28sp` programmatically. So i used the below code.

```
txt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.twenty_eight_sp));
```

But the above code is adding the `28sp` to `32sp`. So the font became too large. I don't want to add the font size, I want to set a new font size.

Can anyone suggest me.

Comment: use TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX instead of TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP
refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14540293/get-dimension-from-xml-and-set-text-size-in-runtime?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 8):

You have to change it to `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX` because `getDimension(id)` returns a `dimen` value from resources and implicitly converted to `px`.

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 
           getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.result_font));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
txt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.twenty_eight_sp));
```

Answer (score 1):

check this link
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setTextSize(int,%20float)

consider both functions as per your requirement

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
txt_home.setTextSize(12);
```